# magento round subtotal, total and tax

Tags: magento, rounding

I have installed the ET Currency Manager in order to sell products by gramm with prices < 0.01 per gramm.

The problem is that this sometimes leads to subtotals, taxes and totals with half cents...which (apart from the paypal problem) is confusing for the customer and not acceptable

Therefore I am searching for a solution to round the subtotal, tax and grand total value to 2 decimal places.

I know that the ET Currency Manager has the option "exclude from checkout" but that leads to other problems wherefore it is not relevant for this question (if I do not get a solution here I will ask this question seperately)

I managed to round the grand total by changing the following function:

app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Grand.php

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $grandTotal     = $address->getGrandTotal();
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();

        $totals     = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());

        $address->setGrandTotal(round(($grandTotal+$totals),2)); //Modificated
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal(round(($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals),2)); //Modificated
        //$address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal+$totals);  --Original
        //$address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals); --Original
        return $this;
    }
```

Is there a way to simultaneously round the subtotal and tax?
I tried to do so in the other files in the above mentioned directory but without result.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old but I had exactly the same problem recently. So here is my solution which seems to work fine so far.

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $grandTotal         = round($address->getGrandTotal(), 2);
    $baseGrandTotal     = round($address->getBaseGrandTotal(), 2);
    $subTotal           = round($address->getSubtotal(), 2);
    $baseSubTotal       = round($address->getBaseSubtotal(), 2);
    $taxAmount          = round($address->getTaxAmount(), 2);
    $baseTaxAmount      = round($address->getBaseTaxAmount(), 2);
    $shippingAmount     = round($address->getShippingAmount(), 2);
    $baseShippingAmount = round($address->getBaseShippingAmount(), 2);

    $address->setSubtotal($subTotal);
    $address->setBaseSubtotal($baseSubTotal);

    $address->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);
    $address->setBaseTaxAmount($baseTaxAmount);     

    $address->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
    $address->setBaseShippingAmount($baseShippingAmount);

    $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $subTotal + $shippingAmount + $taxAmount);
    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $baseSubTotal + $baseShippingAmount + $baseTaxAmount);

    return $this;
}
```